# Bootstrap: Stretching navbar-toggle button in media query

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have started making a simple website using Bootstrap.
Everything works fine, but because I've put my logo in navbar-header , the button does quite funky when going under 407px (407 due to the logo size).

Currently, it is like this (>407px wide):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4RHZ.png

When under 407, it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMDoN.png

I want it to look like this:
(Click the previous link, replace #1 by #2, "I don't have enough reputation...")

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks! Please let me know if you want any further details.
-Jack

EDIT: This is the code that makes up the complete header:

```
<div class="navbar-header" id="header">
    <a href="//www.itsthejackpot.net" class="navbar-brand" id="logo">
        <img src="/images/itsthejackpot.png" alt="itsthejackpot.net">
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar" id="button">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I've seen many people complain about the use of `span` inside a `button`, but it works fine.

Comment: Why would you want it to look stretched like that? Wouldn't it be better if the logo image gets smaller?

Comment: Can you give the code which you are using to put the image in the page?

Comment: @wazaaaap I tried that, but the button would stay under it anyway. If you know how, please let me know

Comment: Add this to your css and tell me if its working: .navbar-brand img {width: 100%;}

Comment: @wazaaaap It doesn't,  the image stays the same

Comment: Please make JSFiddle with the full navbar.

Comment: @wazaaaap I'm not really good with JSFiddle, but itsthejackpot.net is the site I am building and where the problem is. Have a look there.

Comment: @wazaaaap Could you take a look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best way to do it but you can use it temporarily:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    #logo, #logo img {
        width: 230px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        height: 30px;
    }
}
```